# VirtualBox ping one way with bridge

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox

I have Windows 10 as my PC system.
I have installed VirtualBox and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as virtual OS.
I set network card (in VBox) to bridge mode with **static IP 192.168.0.250**.
My Windows 10 card has **static IP 192.168.0.200**.

I can ping from Windows 10 to address **192.168.0.250** (*Ubuntu*), but can't do it from *Ubuntu* to **192.168.0.200** (*Windows*).
Ubuntu allow me to ping my gateway (**192.168.0.1**).

I use Wi-Fi connection.

What can be the problem? Can't I have two IP's maybe?

I want connect two way, in can be another solution, it don't have to be bridge mode if there is better way.

Comment: Please don't put 'solved' in the title. Mark the answer as accepted, which you may not be able to do for a couple of days on your own question, if you're new. It works better for the site in the long run, & also your own rep points, short-term.

Answer (score 0):

I had Bitdefender as firewall and I had to change my firewall hide network setting for Wi-Fi card to OFF, so card can be seen and used in and outside my network.

Now, I can ping two ways in bridge mode with VirtualBox.